# Is there an elegant way to select an element in JQuery if another does not exist?

Tags: jquery, dom, jquery-selectors

Suppose I have the following requirement: Add the element `e` to the element with id `"x"` if such an element exists, otherwise add `e` to the body.

In DOM level 0, I can write:

```
var parent = document.getElementById("x") || document.body;
parent.appendChild(e);
```

In jQuery, the following does *not* work:

```
var parent = $("#x") || $("body");
parent.append(e);
```

because if no element with id `x` exists, the first disjunct returns the empty jquery object, with is truthy, not falsy, so the `append` does nothing.  I *can*, however, write:

```
var parent = $("#x")[0] || $("body")[0];
parent.appendChild(e);
```

but this solution is somewhat clunky because indexing the jQuery object gets me back to HTMLElements, so I must use `appendChild` instead of `append`.  While this works, I am wondering whether this mixing of levels is appropriate or indicative of bad design.

Might there be a way to use `first()`?  Perhaps I could create a jQuery object that was essentially an array whose first element was the div with id x, and the second was the body.  I know I can do this with the jQuery constructor form that takes an element array, but then I am back to a mixing of levels.  I also know how to check for the existence of an element with id x (`$("#x").length`), but I cannot see how this will lead to an elegant way to phrase "the element with id x if it exists, else the body."

Does such a formulation exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using jQuery to select the element, you could use it to wrap the native DOM calls:

```
$(document.getElementById("foo") || document.body)
```

It's not exactly elegant (or really even using jQuery), nor a universally applicable technique, but you'll end up with something you can append to (and incur a relatively inexpensive jQuery invocation just the once).

You won't be able to use `first()` -- e.g., `$("#foo, body").first();` -- because the order in which it returns selected elements is based on DOM order, not selector order (thanks, @muistooshort)

Comment: Ooh, this is pretty, though — unless jQuery works some really serious magic here — it has the performance downside of selecting *all* the elements before returning the first one instead of short-circuiting. Still, if we care about that level of performance, we really shouldn't be using jQuery in the first place.

Comment: No, this won't work since ["The order of the DOM elements in the returned jQuery object may not be identical, as they will be in document order."](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/), for example: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/edYY6/. This will give you `<body>` every time.

Comment: Agreed that this is very nice.  We're okay with the one of each though (or should be), because the first one has an id, which should be unique on the page, and the second is **the** body element.  There should only be one of these in HTML.

Comment: @muistooshort: ack, well spotted. That's a shame :(

Comment: Nice as always, @muistooshort.  Just saw that in my test.

Comment: Unfortunately the same thing happens with `$(a).add(b)`, they come out in DOM-order.

Comment: I like this new version of the answer, too! Might run into trouble if the given query was a simplification and the actual one is like `#parent form.semantic fieldset:nth-child(2)`, but if it's just an ID selector I think we're good to go.

Comment: yeah, you're right on the oversimplification front. I guess it comes down to whether you want a robust solution or a rigid yet elegant solution. More often than not, they're opposite ends of the spectrum :P

Comment: Actually it was not an oversimplification; the problem really is to use a specifically-id'd element if it is present, otherwise to just attach the element to the end of the body.  I'm kind of surprised there does not seem to be a "first"-like JQuery-only formulation, but since jquery uses sets I understand.  The level-mixing (DOM/JQuery) bothered me at first but hey there's a good deal of JQuery out there with HTML _text_ (e.g., `$("<td>Hi</td>")`) which seems perfectly acceptable, as is the jquery "constructor" that takes DOM elements.

Answer (score 3):

Honestly, I don't really think this is exceedingly verbose:

```
var parent = $('#x');
if(parent.length == 0) parent = $('body');
```

And its intent is also quite clear. You could even wrap it in a function if this idiom comes up a lot.

Also, here's a ternary form that only fires each query once (though it's a trade-off on readability):

```
var parent = (x = $('#header')).length ? x : $('body');
```

Comment: You could also use `$("#x").length ? $("#x") : $("body")`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.  I kind of feel bad asking for a one-liner (too common on SO, I know!!) but I was surprised that since DOM Level 0 had a concise formulation then jquery probably should. :)

Comment: @RayToal: added a well-performing one-liner, though it's distinctly less readable. I'd still vote making it one line by wrapping the two-line version in a function, especially if it comes up a lot… but if it's only used once, then meh.

Comment: Agree that the one-liner is less readable, but thanks! Upvoted for the first answer.